# Same message different date

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Good day to everyone,

The thing is, I am making a message application. First, a message is written to `Texfield` , then the message is saved in database by pressing the button.

**Save message**

```
var _mesajCont = TextEditingController();
...
onPressed: () async {
            if (_mesajCont.text.trim().length > 0) {
              Mesaj _kaydedilecMesaj = Mesaj(
                  bendenMi: true,
                  message: _mesajCont.text,
                  kimden: _chatModel.currentUser!.userID,
                  kime: _chatModel.sohbetedilenUser!.userID);

              var sonuc = await _chatModel.saveMessage(_kaydedilecMesaj); <--- SAVE MESSAGE
              
              if (sonuc) {
                _mesajCont.clear();
              }
            }
          },
```

**Database Service** (SAVE MESSAGE AND GET MESSAGE METHOD HERE)

```
Future<bool> saveMessage(Mesaj kaydedilecMesaj) async {
var mesajID = _firestoreDB.collection("konusmalar").doc().id;
var _myDocID = kaydedilecMesaj.kimden + "--" + kaydedilecMesaj.kime;
var _alici = kaydedilecMesaj.kime + "--" + kaydedilecMesaj.kimden;
var _kaydedilecMap = kaydedilecMesaj
    .toMap(); // bundan nesne üretince false sorunu düzeldi ilginc
await _firestoreDB
    .collection("konusmalar")
    .doc(_myDocID)
    .collection("mesajlar")
    .doc(mesajID)
    .set(_kaydedilecMap);

await _firestoreDB.collection("konusmalar").doc(_myDocID).set({
  "konusma_sahibi": kaydedilecMesaj.kimden,
  "kimle_konusuyor": kaydedilecMesaj.kime,
  "son_yollanan_mesaj": kaydedilecMesaj.message,
  "konusma_goruldu": false,
  "olusturulma_tarihi": FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
});

_kaydedilecMap.update("bendenMi", (value) => false);

await _firestoreDB
    .collection("konusmalar")
    .doc(_alici)
    .collection("mesajlar")
    .doc(mesajID)
    .set(_kaydedilecMap);

await _firestoreDB.collection("konusmalar").doc(_alici).set({
  "konusma_sahibi": kaydedilecMesaj.kime,
  "kimle_konusuyor": kaydedilecMesaj.kimden,
  "son_yollanan_mesaj": kaydedilecMesaj.message,
  "konusma_goruldu": false,
  "olusturulma_tarihi": FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
});

return true;
}
Stream<List<Mesaj>> getMassage(
  String currentUserID, String sohbetEdilenUserID) {
var snapShot = _firestoreDB
    .collection("konusmalar")
    .doc(currentUserID + "--" + sohbetEdilenUserID)
    .collection("mesajlar")
    //.where("konusma_sahibi", isEqualTo: currentUserID)
    .orderBy("date", descending: true /*tarihi son olanı öne koyar*/)
    .limit(1)
    .snapshots();

return snapShot.map((mesajListesi) =>
    mesajListesi.docs.map((mesaj) => Mesaj.fromMap(mesaj.data())).toList());

}
```

After that I used the `Consumer` structure to listen for new messages.

```
Widget _buildMesajListesi() {
return Consumer<ChatViewModel>(builder: (context, value, child) {
  return Expanded(
    child: ListView.builder(
      reverse: true,
      controller: _scrollCont,
      itemBuilder: ((context, index) {
        
          return talkingBalloon(value.mesajlarListesi![index]); <--New talking baloon
        
      }),
      itemCount: value.dahaVarmii
          ? value.mesajlarListesi!.length + 1
          : value.mesajlarListesi!.length,
    ),
  );
});
}
```

Then I created a method to listen for new messages when the page is opened.

**ChatViewModel.dart**

```
List<Mesaj>? _tumMesajlar;
List<Mesaj>? get mesajlarListesi => _tumMesajlar;
.....
void yeniMesajListenerGet() {
_userRepository
    .getMessage(currentUser!.userID, sohbetedilenUser!.userID)
    .listen((anlikData) {
  debugPrint("LISTENER GET DATA=>>>${anlikData[0].toString()}"); 

  if (anlikData[0] != null) {
    if (_listeyeilkMesaj!.date!.millisecondsSinceEpoch !=
        anlikData[0].date!.millisecondsSinceEpoch) {
      _tumMesajlar!.insert(0, anlikData[0]);
    }
  }
});
}
```

Here's the problem, I send a message once, a message is registered in the database, but `listen` works 2 times and the response in the console is:>

> LISTENER GET DATA=>>>WHO XzAHsfvxmYUqHirg5eH7ifT0Qtf1, TO WHO WoxT4Nxomeh1MQOE6p8eOadgRYa2, ME-> true, MESSAGE same message but diff timeStamp, TİMESTAMP Timestamp(seconds=1679296897, nanoseconds=792506000)

> LISTENER GET DATA=>>>WHO XzAHsfvxmYUqHirg5eH7ifT0Qtf1, TO WHO WoxT4Nxomeh1MQOE6p8eOadgRYa2, ME-> true, MESSAGE same message but diff timeStamp, TİMESTAMP Timestamp(seconds=1679296914,nanoseconds=30000000) <--- database timestamp

Different dates (database success image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5znHz.png))

I tried to share a lot of details so that it is easy to understand. Please let me know if you see anything missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added `Timestamp .now()` to the `date` part of the `Mesaj.fromMap` method so that it does not return null. I removed it, now the initial value returns null and after the firebase is saved message, the actual date returns. I got rid of the data that returned null with the condition.

```
Mesaj.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map).......
    date = map['date'] /*?? Timestamp.now()*/, <--
    message = map['message'];
```

**display in console:**

> LISTENER GET DATA=>>>MESSAGE hhjggrhhg, TİMESTAMP null
>
> LISTENER GET DATA=>>>MESSAGE hhjggrhhg, TİMESTAMP
> Timestamp(seconds=1679379294, nanoseconds=812000000)

and little change in `if`

```
.getMessage(currentUser!.userID, sohbetedilenUser!.userID)
    .listen((anlikData) {
  debugPrint("LISTENER GET DATA=>>>${anlikData[0].toString()}");

  if (anlikData[0].date != null) { <-- here added .date 
    _tumMesajlar!.insert(0, anlikData[0]);     
  }
```

any different idea? please share.